error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement' not found
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
com.coherent.EarHealth.app-mergeDebugResources-47:/values-v35/values-v35.xml:4: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement' not found.
error: failed linking references.

I'm facing this style attribute error in my flutter project.
style.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>


style.xml (values-night)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>


app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" 
}
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.22'
}
android {
    namespace "com.coherents.Project"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "27.0.12077973"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.coherents.Project"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Project"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']}}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") ||
                project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
            project.android {
                compileSdkVersion 34
                buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}


In your build.gradle file, inside your android block you are compiling and targeting API level 34:
android {
    namespace "com.coherents.Project"
    compileSdkVersion 34  // <---- HERE
    ndkVersion "27.0.12077973"
    ....
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.coherents.Project"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34 // <--- HERE
    ...
   }
}

but the attribute windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement was only added in API level 35.
So you need to at least change your compileSdkVersion to API level to 35.

This does not work for me

did you find any workaround i have set target and compile to 35 still getting same error

@SunilChaudhary - You would have to provide more information in order for people to understand your issue better. I can suggest asking a new question and adding all the relevant details there.

I'm having same issue since i upgraded to flutter 3.27.1, i'm using some packages and i think the problem comes from there
